# How to execute a one-line posix dash command within dash script to enable coredump?

Tags: shell-script, posix, dash, core-dump

For unrelated purposes I am forced to produce a script that only works with posix sh.

Within my script I have checked if the system allows the creation of coredumps, then if the limit is set to 0 I want the script to attempt to run `ulimit -c unlimited`.

I have attempted, to no luck, within the script:

1. `sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited"`
2. `ulimit -c unlimited`

Within my general zsh terminal attempting the first failed, yet if I ran sh then the second command manually it worked.

As such, for the purposes of being placed in a larger posix sh script, how can I run these commands to enable the core dumps?

Comment: To enable core dumps for what? The resource limits set by `ulimit` are inherited from one process to another, so if you want the commands started by your shell to be able to dump core, you need to have the _shell_ increase the limit for core dumps. That is, you can't use a script to change it so that it would affect the parent shell. That's why `ulimit` is a built-in command in shells.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The script is looping through the execution of a program with a variety of input, and when a particular input causes a segfault and produces a coredump I want to be able to save each one. At the moment, as far as I'm led to believe, as ulimit -c is set to 0 this is stopping the production. Therefore I wanted to test for this and try to resolve it within the script itself.
The aim is to be able to inspect each core dump afterwards in relation to its given test input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ulimit` is really underdefined in the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ulimit.html), it only seems to know about `ulimit -f`, so we can't count on the standard in avoiding any issues.

However, `ulimit -c unlimited` works in all shells I tried: Bash, Dash (Debian's `/bin/sh`), Busybox, zsh, ksh and yash. I don't know about the ksh-variants on BSDs.

Note that the resource limits set by `ulimit` are inherited from a process to its children, so a setting in the script only affects processes launched by the script. Namely, that `sh -c "ulimit -c unlimited"` will be useless: it'll only change the limit of that particular shell, which immediately exits after setting the limit.

Of course setting the limit may fail, for example a hard limit may be set, preventing you from raising the limit. So you might want to do some error checking on the `ulimit` call:

```
if ! ulimit -c unlimited; then
    echo "error: something went wrong when setting core dump limit" >&2
    exit 1
fi
# do something here that might dump core
```

That should work for most shells, but it looks like in zsh, `ulimit` always returns a successful status, and gives no errors even if it fails (oddly enough). So in zsh, you'd need to read to limit afterwards to check if it was set correctly, e.g.:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
if [ "$(ulimit -c)" != unlimited ]; then
    echo "error: core dump limit wasn't set" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Of course, your system might have other things that could also influence creating core files.

Comment: What confused me is that within my script, I could successfully return ```ulimit -c``` to get the figure, but as soon as I tried to set it with ```ulimit -c unlimited``` it failed to work. Further, it was confusing when I could enter sh in zsh, and manually write the commands out and exit, and it would be successfully reflected in zsh, but trying to do it as a passed argument to sh was a failure. Thanks

Comment: @PlantAgenetKing, how does it fail? Any error message? There's also the concept of "hard" limits which limit how high you can raise the regular limit. Try and see what `ulimit -Hc` says.

Comment: It simply does not return anything, yet does not exit on failure. It is only on checking afterwards you can see it is still set to 0. Perhaps this is a reflection of your point on only being valid within the sh shell for the command, and reverting on exit. Thank you for all the help and I shall implement the exit error checking instead as suggested, it is by no means critical to me though I just thought I could keep it tidy within the script.

Comment: @PlantAgenetKing, all shells I tried also print an error and give a falsy exit status if they can't set the limit. ...Except zsh, for whatever reason, it just fails silently, no error, successful exit, which is a bit surprising. The manual seems to say that "if it fails to set a limit for some other reason [than a malformed argument] it will continue trying to set the remaining limits.", but I'm not really sure how it's useful to just give a success if nothing succeeded.

Comment: So it seems in zsh you'd need to do `ulimit -c unlimited; if [ "$(ulimit -c)" != unlimited ]; then echo error...; exit; fi`...

Comment: I can't upvote due to lack of reputation, but thank you again for the time and input.

Comment: @PlantAgenetKing, if the answer helped and acceptably solved your problem, you can "accept" the answer from the check mark next to it. You can only accept one answer from every question that way. Questions with accepted answers show slightly differently in some lists, so it's also a way of keeping track of which questions on the site are still "open".

Answer (score 0):

The current POSIX text lists:

```
ulimit [-H|-S] -a

ulimit [-H|-S] [-c|-d|-f|-n|-s|-t|-v] [newlimit]
```

so the POSIX standard does contain `ulimit -c corelimit`...

What you may have missed is that the related limitation is controlled by a call to `setrlimit()` and that call only controls the limits for the process that calls `setrlimit()` or the children of that process.

Since you tried to call `ulimit ...` in a subshell, the settings only apply to that subshell and it's potential children.

In other words, you need to call `ulimit` in your current shell in order to make the settings valid for your current work environment. If you like a shortcut, you may set up an `alias` for that command or write a script, but such a script needs to be called via the `dot` command (.) in order to become effective to your working shell.